# Await or wait async method SignalR for Android

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, signalr

I am using signalr java client and I want to use something like await in c# for my signalr methods, something similar to the following:

```
    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {

       hubProxy.invoke(Categories[].class, "ListOfCategories").done(new Action<Categories[]>() {

             @Override
             public void run(final Categories[] Categories) throws Exception {

                .....
             }
        });// Want to use something like await o wait in c# in this method because is asycn
     }
```

How should I go about implementing this functionality?

Comment: If you hang the ui thread in android your application will crash with an "application not responding" error. Instead use your callback to update whatever you need to update. If you're dead set on crashing your app look into wait/notify and Thread.join.

Comment: You can read [this link](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2013/11/01/How-To-Use-SignalR-in-iOS-and-Android-Apps.aspx?m=1&Page=2) to see if it looks like your case or not. However, they used Xamarin.